# Path problem for php CURL request with pem and a key

Tags: php, ssl, curl, plesk

I was using a curl request with third party pem certificate in IIS windows based server which is:

```
$userAgent = 'Third party name';
$headers = array(
    "SOAPAction:",
    "Content-Type: text/xml; charset = utf-8",
    "Connection: close"
);
$cURL = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $this->baseURL());
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $soap);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $certificateURL);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $this->certPass);
$response = curl_exec($cURL);
curl_close($cURL);
return $response;
```

the $certificateURL in windows was

```
$certificateURL = "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/api/kx2.pem"
```

and it was working fine.

Now this is shifted to a Linux server and I am using plesk for this, the cert pem file is in the same directory with code but the here is I assigned

```
$certificateURL = "./kx2.pem";
```

and to

```
$certificateURL = "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/api/kx2.pem";
```

it doesn't work, it gives error msg

> could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error error:140AB18F:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate:ee key too small,
> (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)

what should I do I have tried many things changed the whole curl request even tried `__DIR__` based url?

Comment: You should probably check the key size and make sure it is at least 2048. Seems like newer versions of OpenSSL require that.

Comment: Whether `kx2.pem` is in same folder ?

Comment: Well Chris I have converted a pfx to pem it is working fine in IIS server but in plesk it shows error, if you look at the curl request its using a static key as well so which key you are talking about?

Comment: Kumar yes it in the same folder, where the curl request file is.

Answer (score 0):

You error suggest that the `.pem` file is missing the `key`. Make sure it is included. Using PERL for instance you can do this to make the `.pem` file:

```
use File::Slurp;
my $content_key = read_file("C:\\Apache24\\conf\\ssl.key\\$zone_name.key");
my $content_crt = read_file("C:\\Apache24\\conf\\ssl.crt\\$zone_name.crt");
my $content_pem = $content_crt.$content_key;

write_file("C:\\Apache24\\conf\\ssl.pem\\$zone_name.pem", $content_pem);
```